# Unable to get Repeatedly.forever triggering working in my pipeline

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Currently developing a Beam pipeline using Flinkrunner and Apache Beam 2.29.

As per suggestion in Beam File processing patterns, I have an unbound pipeline listening to a Kafka topic for a CSV filename and once received processes it through TextIO readFile().

We end up with two PCollections, one is from the file being processed and the other is from a lookup from an external datastore. The PCollections are joined using the Join extension which forces us to setup some triggering on these two PCollections. So I have defined something like the below for each PCollection in hopes that the end result following the join would produce some new output every time a new filename arrives from the Kafka topic we are monitoring.

```
PCollection<KV<String, Map<String, AttributeValue>>> lookupTable = LookupTable.getPspLookupData(p, lookupTableName, lookupTableRegionFilter)
            .apply("WindowB", Window.<KV<String, Map<String, AttributeValue>>>into(new GlobalWindows())
                    .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(15))))
                    .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardSeconds(5))
                    .discardingFiredPanes()
            );
```

But it simply does not work more than once. It seems that if I send one or more kafka messages before the 15 seconds defined in *plusDelayOf()* the data gets processed but anything sent past those 15 seconds (from pipeline startup) is never processed and the pipeline is simply "stuck" despited having defined a trigger of *Repeatedly.forever*...

I have tried numerous combinations and I simply cant get it to work. Would welcome any ideas or suggestions to get this to work. Feels like I am missing something basic but I have been at this for hours.

Thanks,
Serge